# Redirected to unsafe page on freshly installed Windows 10

Tags: virus, dns, router, url-redirection

*This is my first question in security, so let me know if something about the question should be fixed.*

**Some background information:**
My Windows 10 laptop was starting to get realy, realy slow when browsing the internet (Chrome lagged alot when fetching simple pages like www.google.com). However i could still play rather demanding games without too much trouble. A week ago i got a call from my internet provider telling me a unit was sending spam-emails from the IP of my appartement.

To try to fix this, i ran a full AVG-scan on both my Windows 10 units (nothing was found). I also had a raspberry pi, open for SSH-Connections with default username and password (very bad practise, i know) which i turned off and disconnected.

My guess was that is was the PI that was responsible for the spam-emails. But since my main laptop was much slower than it should be, i did a fresh install of Windows 10 today, through a bootable USB.

**Now to my problem:**
The first thing i did, on the new Windows 10, was to open edge and type www.google.com, but i got no response, just a blank page, tried closing Edge and redo, same issue. Then i tried Internet Explorer and i typed in www.google.se, and i somehow ended up at a "There are hot womens in your neighbourhood"-site (the domain ended in `rsc.cdn77.org`).

**My question:** 
What can be the reason i was redirected to that page on a freshly installed Windows 10 and should i still be worried? Can my router be infected (its a standard router from my internet provider on which i could not lockate the DNS on)? Can another unit on my WiFi be infected and cause this (the only other units connected was two Android phones, a TiVo and a couple of chromecasts according too me and according too the status page on my router)?

Comment: Did you get the software from the bootable USB from somewhere reliable (such as Microsoft)?  If not, I would suspect that the new install of Windows came with viruses pre-loaded.

Comment: It came from Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your router has been infected by a dns hijacking malware.

Comment: Can that be fixed by simply resetting the router (i.e. pressing the reset button at the back)? Or can it be infected at a deeper level?

Comment: It depends on the malware and the router but you might want to give it a try